# Trying to merge two arrays together

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have two arrays, that I'm simply trying to merge together in a function:

```
$var1=array();
$myInputVar=array();
$var1['something']['secondary_something'][]="foo1";
$var1['something']['secondary_something'][]="foo2";
$var1['something']['secondary_something'][]="foo3";

$myInputVar['something']['secondary_something'][]="foo4";
$myInputVar['something']['secondary_something'][]="foo5";

function something(&$array_, $array_new) {
   $array = array_merge($array_ , $array_new); 

    print_r($array);//for debugging

}   
something($var1, $myInputVar);
```

Now that prints:

```
Array ( [something] => Array ( [secondary_something] => Array ( [0] => foo1 [1] => foo2 [2] => foo3 ) ) )
```

When I was expecting:

```
Array ( [something] => Array ( [secondary_something] => Array ( [0] => foo1 [1] => foo2 [2] => foo3 [3] => foo4 [4] => foo5) ) )
```

I've also tried:

```
$array = $array_ + $array_new;
```

Which still doesn't print what I'm expecting.

I have a feeling I've misunderstood the purpose of the `array_merge()` function, which is why its not returning the result I'm expecting it to return.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code should print: `Array ( [something] => Array ( [secondary_something] => Array ( [0] => foo4 [1] => foo5 ) ) ) `

Comment: array_merge works from left to right. Run the OP's code and the results will be as I've described.

Comment: @webbiedave The code above is my exact code, and it is returning `Array ( [something] => Array ( [secondary_something] => Array ( [0] => foo1 [1] => foo2 [2] => foo3 ) ) )`

Comment: @nav_nav: Very strange indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://php.net/array-merge-recursive).

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge` will work from left to right. In your case:

```
$array_['something']['secondary_something']
```

will be overwritten by

```
$array_new['something']['secondary_something']
```

You could do the following:

```
function something(&$array_, $array_new) {
    $array = array_merge($array_ , $array_new); 
    return $array;
}

$var1['something']['secondary_something'] = something($var1['something']['secondary_something'], $myInputVar['something']['secondary_something']);
```

Otherwise, you'll want to create a function that is aware of the associative keys and will combine the arrays appropriately.

Comment: `array_merge_recursive()` seemed to do the trick. Thanks anyway xD

Answer (score 0):

```
function something(&$array_, $array_new) {
    foreach ($array_new as $val)
        foreach ($val as $val2)
            foreach ($val2 as $val3)
                array_push($array_['something']['secondary_something'], $val3);
    print_r($array_);//for debugging
}
```